# change the foreground Color of a TextBlock when Hover in a universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a ListView,in which I want to assign a Style when I hover on each ListViewItem
this is My Style:Details.xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listmee">
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
           <Grid>     
               <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>  
               <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">     
               <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/> 
               <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">   
               <Storyboard>    
                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#d9d7ec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="listItem1" />                                                                                                           
                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />  
               </Storyboard> 
               </VisualState>    
               <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">    
               <Storyboard>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#d9d7ec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="listItem1" />        
                   <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />                                                                                                                                       </Storyboard>                                                                    </VisualState>                                                                </VisualStateGroup>                                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

           <Grid>
  <Rectangle x:Name="listItem1" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent"  />
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1"/>
           </Grid>
        </Grid>
     </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Orientation="Horizontal">  
                   <TextBlock  x:Name="day" Text="{Binding Path=nom_jour}"   Foreground="Gray" ></TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
             <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Orientation="Horizontal">                                                          
                  <TextBlock x:Name="hour_deb" Text="{Binding Path=deb_jour}" Foreground="Gray"></TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView>
```

The problem is that my code changes the background color of ListviewItem when Hover but the Text color doese not change when hover
any idea please in How can I fix it
thanks for help

Update:
I have used a UserControl to apply the Style on my ListView like this:

Details.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
            <local:ListViewTemplate Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="listmee" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}">
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <!--I have put here the Style-->
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Details.xaml.cs:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  { 
  getDaysHours();
}
        private async void getDaysHours()
        {
              UriString2 = "webService;
                var http = new HttpClient();
                http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString2);
                var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

                listmee.ItemsSource = rootObject1.horaire_local; 
        }
```

ListViewTemplate.xaml:(UserControl file)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock   x:Name="day" Text="{Binding Path=nom_jour}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <TextBlock x:Name="hour_deb" Text="{Binding Path=deb_jour}" />
          <TextBlock x:Name="hour_fin" Text="{Binding Path=fin_jour}"/> 
            </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

when I load the page I get an empty List,miss I an thing in my code??

Comment: It's because the TextBlock is out of the ListViewItem template. You could create a UserControl for DataTemplate, put the TextBlock in it and change its Color when pointer hovers.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply but with a UserControl I did not get any list in my Listview

Comment: I have updated my Post